# 6 IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "int" exists

Tags: c++, string, validation

Hey im validating a string.

```
string getString(string q)
{
    string input;

    do
    {
        cout << q.c_str() << endl;
        cin >> input;
    } while (!isalpha(input));

    return input;
}
```

When using `while(!isalpha(input));`  input gives that error.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve through the condition in there?

Comment: `isalpha` is a C function, taking a single character, no? If so, feeding it a `std::string` won't work since there's no string to `char` or `int` cast.

Comment: @CodingMash I have Please enter your name?  When the user enters the name.  I want them to not be able to enter numbers.  And if the suer does not enter only strings.  Keep prompting them until they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12958948/241631) describes what the problem is, but here's a solution that makes use of [algorithms from the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) instead of writing your own (example requires C++11)

```
bool all_alpha( std::string const& s )
{
  return std::all_of( s.cbegin(), s.cend(), static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::isalpha) );
}
```

The above function will return true only if all characters in the string are alphabetic. If you only want to disallow numeric characters, I'd use a slightly different function.

```
bool any_digit( std::string const& s )
{
  return std::any_of( s.cbegin(), s.cend(), static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::isdigit) );
}
```

or

```
bool no_digits( std::string const& s )
{
  return std::none_of( s.cbegin(), s.cend(), static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::isdigit) );
}
```

Use these functions to validate the input that you receive from the user.

---

If you can't use C++11 features, the functions can be modified to use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead, and compare the return value of `find_if` to `s.end()` to determine success / failure.

Comment: I looked for an existing function but I did not thought about algorithms. +1

Answer (score 1):

The [isalpha](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt82b8z8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function takes an integer as a parameter, but you are passing it a `std::string`. You could write a function like this to test if your string contains only alphabetical characters:

```
bool   noDigitInString(std::string str)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
  {
    if (isdigit(str[i]))
      return false;
   }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but when i done this string input1 ="What is your name?\n";
 string name = getString(input1);  I have an error on the method.

Comment: Well `?` is not an alphanumerical character, nor is `\n`, so `isStringAlpha` will return false. Modify the `if` statement to fit your needs

Comment: How exactly would i modify the if?  Is there a function similar to isalpha for ? \\\ etc....

Comment: I just took out the ? and the \n and the error is still occuring :S

Comment: Yes, a space is not an alphanumerical character either. From the comment on your question, I understand you only want to exclude digits, then you can say `if (isdigit(str[i]))`

Comment: 9 IntelliSense: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "bool" to "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>"  @ Zoneur. Do you understand this ?

Comment: string input1 ="What is your name ?\n";
 string name = getString(input1); The getString produces the error :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18241/discussion-between-zoneur-and-pendo826)